# Add "open containing folder" to context Menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

How can I add to the context menu , another item which opens the *current* file in its folder ?

I tried with `shift + right click` but nothing appears :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to right-click a file(not a shortcut) and be able to open its location in explorer. I'm not sure why you would want that, considering the file would already be in its folder and shortcut links already have an option for that in windows 7.

In any case, the following might help:

- Open regedit.exe (by typing it into the start menu).
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` , right-click `shell` > `New` > `Key` and name it "Open Containing Folder".
- Right-click the key you just created and create another key named "command".
- Double-click `(Default)` and give it the following value.

> "explorer.exe" /select,"%1"

This is what it should look like:

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Regarding why -- search results via windows search or total commander search - so i need to access the folder sometimes

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xeoMz.jpg (ps your solution works)

Comment: Also inside Save / Open File Dialog